# Appengine LogService has an undocumented quota - up to 1000000 reads per day, know a way to workaround?

Tags: google-app-engine, service, logging, quota, quotas

Appengine LogService has an undocumented quota:
You can make up to a 1,000,000 reads from it per day, and then you'll receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/xxx/3.356325783019142341/xxx.py", line 355, in get
    for request_log in logservice.fetch(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, version_ids=["3"]):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 414, in __iter__
    self._advance()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 427, in _advance
    response)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 308, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 133, in CheckSuccess
    raise self.exception
OverQuotaError: The API call logservice.Read() required more quota than is available.
```

Also, when you reach this quota, you'll start see the following on your dashboard (AFAIK you don't see this line there before):
[image]

At that point it's not documented at all, and it seems it isn't billable too.

See this too: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/61fac55e1a2d521

Hope it'll save you some time.

Let me know if you can think on a workaround... (just to make it a question ;) )

Comment: Feel free to file a docs bug, but this isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can request to have your limits increased: http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?&contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest