# Google App engine says:--- Over quota error---logservice.Read() required more quota

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, quota

I read **log files programmatically using logservice.fetch()**
After a certain number of reads **OVER QUOTA error comes up**
Is there any way to avoid this. I did not find anything in the documentation[even in billing]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989690/appengine-logservice-has-an-undocumented-quota-up-to-1000000-reads-per-day-kn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its undocumented but log service has a 1,000,000 reads per day limit.